# Add AWS ECR lifecycle policy which do not start with specific tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I am having a requirement where I want to remove the AWS ECR images which do not start with specific tag let's say test is the tag after 10 days.

I read AWS documentation so there I can see we can create AWS ECR lifecycle policy for the specific tag. Means if there are any images whose tag start with test1 can be removed after 10 days but I don't found any documentation where it says that we can remove an ECR images whose tag doesn't start with test.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?